# Pandas dataframe - check if multiple rows have the same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame which looks like this :

| Reference | Value |
| --- | --- |
| String1 | 1 |
| String2 | 0 |
| String3 | -1 |
| String2 | 1 |
| String1 | 1 |
| String3 | 0 |

Each reference can appear in the dataframe either once, two times, or three times ; and can have either the same or different value associated.
I would like to create another dataframe which tells me, for each Reference, do they all have the same value or not. So with the example above, I would like to get something like this :

| Reference | Value |
| --- | --- |
| String1 | Yes |
| String2 | No |
| String3 | No |

(I put Yes and No as an example but it could be 1/0 or whatever else)

How can I do this ?

My initial thought was to use a `.groupby` but then I didn't find any type of aggregation which would help me here...

Answer (score 3):

You could use `groupby` + `nunique` to get a count of unique Values for each Reference. Then use `np.where` to assign Yes/No values depending on if the number of unique values is 1 or not:

```
out = df.groupby('Reference', as_index=False)['Value'].nunique()
out['Value'] = np.where(out['Value'].eq(1), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Output:

```
  Reference Value
0   String1   Yes
1   String2    No
2   String3    No
```

Comment: `df.groupby("Reference").Value.nunique().eq(1).replace({True: "Yes", False: "No"}).reset_index()`