# how to merge rows of a df with same value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am facing a problem using pandas on python and i can't solve it.
I would like to merge/combine/regroup the rows which have the same url.

EDIT :
I have a dataframe looking like this :

| url | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa |  | xx | yy |  |
| bbb | zz |  |  |  |
| aaa | ee |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | AA |

I would like something like this :

| url | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | ee | xx | yy |  |
| bbb | zz |  |  | cc |
|  |  |  |  | AA |

I've tried using groupby, but in my df i've datas which don't have URL and i want to keep them.
I've also tried merge with inner, which gives me pretty good results but i don't know why it decuplates the number of rows inside my df.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `first`.

```py
df = df.groupby('url', as_index=False).first()
```

Comment: I don't think this will cover the case where you don't have url.  could you demonstrate "i've datas which don't have URL and i want to keep them" in sample data and expected output?

Comment: Could you update your question to include the data that doesn't have url and explain how those should be kept?  If you have multiple rows without url, what should happen?

Comment: add `dropna=False` in `groupby`?

Comment: there it is, that's what i was looking for! thank you very much Emma!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `groupby, nunique, and np.where` to solve this issue.
See the following discussion regarding this problem.
[pandas-dataframe-check-if-multiple-rows-have-the-same-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229788/pandas-dataframe-check-if-multiple-rows-have-the-same-value)

Comment: thank you for your answer but i want to keep value as they are. Im working with str values.

Comment: Your welcome bro.  Wish you the best of luck.

Comment: you too Mohammad :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'url': ['url1', 'url2'], 'col1':['A', np.nan], 'col2':[np.nan, 'B']}).set_index('url')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'url': ['url1', 'url2'], 'col1':[np.nan, 'C'], 'col2':['D', np.nan]}).set_index('url')
df1.fillna(df2, inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

Result:

```
     col1 col2
url           
url1    A    D
url2    C    B
```